# How can I open a new z shell in a tab and run a command?

Tags: macos, tabs, zsh

I'm on macOS which is currently using the zshell.

I would like to run a command in one shell which opens another shell preferably in another tab in the same window and then runs a given command.  For example:

```
> openTab
```

would open another tab and run a basic command like `ls`.

Is this possible to do?

It appears that the open command will open new window, but I want it to be opened as a new tab in the current window.  See [here](https://scriptingosx.com/2020/03/macos-shell-command-to-create-a-new-terminal-window/)

Osascript appears a bit messy, is there way to do this natively with zshell?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppleScript, via `osascript` to do exactly that:

```sh
function runInNewTab() {  
    osascript >/dev/null <<EOF
    tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down
        end tell
    tell application "Terminal" to do script "$*" in front window
EOF
}
```

Run it like this:

```
runInNewTab ls -l ~
```

Comment: Thanks, I googled extensively, where did you find this, it appears to work when I paste it into the shell.  Can you put it in the form of a function?

Comment: This code will need to be placed in my .zshrc file which is used to config the zshell.

Comment: Haha, I found it in my own brain; AppleScript is really cool :)

Comment: Edited to add function.

Comment: What happened @favor?

Comment: Can I send you a french kiss via SO? xD really thx, you save my tons of repetitive commands...